# TypeError: 'AffineScalarFunc' object is not iterable

Tags: python, loops, object, iterable

I defined a function such as:

```
def ucos(a):
    temp=[umath.cos(i) for i in a]
    return unumpy.uarray([unumpy.nominal_values(i) for i in temp], [unumpy.std_devs(i) for i in temp])
```

But when I try to iterate over it with a for loop:

```
for j in range(len(Beta)):
    if Beta[j]<pi/2.:
       Radius.append((Diam_meas[j]/2.)*(ucos((pi/2)-Beta[j]))**(-1)*10**(-9))
    else:
       Radius.append((Diam_meas[j]/2.)*10**(-9))
```

it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: 'AffineScalarFunc' object is not iterable
```

Do you have any idea on why ucos function is not iterable? How to make it iterable?
thx!

Comment: Being both a Scalar and a Func(tion, I presume) makes the question "why would you expect it to be iterable?"  And what sequence of things are you hoping to iterate over?

Comment: I have Beta with shape(Beta)=(8,) and to each value of Beta is associated a Diam_meas. If Beta is smaller than pi/2 I want to calc the Radius in a different way compared to when Beta is bigger than pi/2. However the ucos function does not accept Beta[j]. why so?

Comment: Have you checked to see what you are passing into `ucos`?

Comment: I often get this kind of error when I use square brackets (`[]`) instead of parentheses (`()`) or the opposite. Couldn't it the be case ?

Comment: Beta is an array, therefore in order to call the j-th element of the array I should use [], not (). @scott I am passing a uarray into ucos

Comment: It looks like Beta is an array of numbers, such that the expression being passed to `ucos` is a number, not an array.  How have you verified what is being passed to `ucos`?

Comment: Thanks @Scott , apparently if I format Beta in ucos() as Beta[[j]] instead of Beta[j] it works. Though it is not clear to me why. Beta is a uarray , i.e. a float with an uncertainty associated.